# Could an HTML tag have < anywhere in it? (In the strings for example)

Tags: html

I know that `<` is not used inside an HTML tag. I know that it is illegal in URIs too. I can deduce that it is also invalid in `class` or `id` of an HTML element. I have never seen it used in styles either.

I need to know however if there is any weird special case that `<` could be entered.

Let me elaborate. I want to match HTML tags in some text and say, throw them away. In this text, `<` is normally escaped (so written like `\<`), but I am assuming there could be user input mistake. So, I want to see if I there is ever a chance that such a thing could be a tag:

```
<.........<......>  <-- the whole thing is a tag
```

(where the `.`s could be anything, such as `"`)

Or could I safely assume the first `<` was a mistake by the user?

---

The question sounds a bit too specific, so I'm going to make it a bit more general: What are the characters that absolutely cannot appear inside an html tag?

Comment: Yes, of course you can always get **invalid** HTML files with invalid characters to work with if you parse user input, other files etc.

Comment: @Smamatti :)) Well yes, but I just wanted to be of a little intelligence in this case and easily detect an un-escaped <

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a title="A title with a < less than symbol">My awesome link</a>
```

Is perfectly valid HTML.

Comment: Since I can't write short comments, here goes: "crap!"

Answer (score 4):

> I can deduce that it is also invalid in `class`

It isn't.

> or `id` of an HTML element

True for HTML 4, but not for HTML 5.

> What are the characters that absolutely cannot appear inside an html tag?

There aren't any. Some might only be able to appear in attribute values, but since they appear inside the tag, any character can.

Comment: You can put an `<` in an ID in HTML5?

Comment: To quote the spec: "The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters."

Comment: Doesn't id create an anchor which therefore can be used in the URL and hence make an invalid URL? Or in that case it is automatically turned to %..?

Comment: So by character, what is the definition of that? Unicode characters?

Comment: @Shahbaz — Other way around. The % encoded character is decoded and then matched.

Comment: No I mean, if you have `id="<"`, then the URL wouldn't be `...#<` right? It would be `....#%we` (where `we` stands for whatever!), am I right?

Comment: @Jared Farrish — I believe HTML 4 was defined in terms of unicode; presumably there is something like that in 5.

Comment: So what has changed in HTML5? On another theme, you could have `id="#"` and `href="##"` would work?

Comment: @Jared Farrish — Many things have changed in HTML 5. You can have `id="#"` and `href="#%23"` but I've no idea what browser support is like.

Comment: On the first question, it's just that you suggest something was invalid in HTML 4 but not in HTML 5. On the second... [Yes, `##` does work](http://jsfiddle.net/rrTMQ/). Paranormal.

Comment: It *is* invalid in HTML 4: 'ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").' (And the value of an ID attribute is a NAME token)

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about their being a clash of HTML tags, and are concerned about the validity of `>`, you can use the encoded HTML `&gt;`:

```
<a href="#" title="My anchor &gt; title">My Link Text</a>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/gKP89/

But as [@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204934/370103) & [@roryf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204938/370103) have pointed out, this shouldn't be an issue.